# How to post json Array to webservice using JSON in android?

Tags: android, json

I have to send the following data to a php web service using JSON

The format of data to be send is:

```
object1{key1:<>,key2:<>Array1({key1<>,key3<>array2 ( {key4:<>,array3({key5:<>}), {}, {},…) }}
```

My problem is: how can I send the array values to the web service?

Answer (score 1):

iam able to add more elemnts to the array. check this

```
JSONArray datarr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject obj1;
    JSONObject Array1 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("array1val", 5);
        obj1.put("array2val", 2);
        datarr.put(obj1);
        }   
        Array1.put("Array1", datarr);
        Log.v(null, Array1.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the out put is

```
{

"Array1":
        [
           {
              "array1val":5,"array2val":2
           },
          {
              "array1val":5,"array2val":2
          },
          {
              "array1val":5,"array2val":2
          },
          {
              "array1val":5,"array2val":2
          }
        ]
}
```

is this what your looking for?

Comment: yha did it. but problem is that i am able to send only one value ata time like: Array1[{"array1val":5,"arrayval2":2:}] in one time ths  Array1[{"array1val":5,"arrayval2":2:},{"array1val":5,"arrayval2":2:}]